# JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Let's say I have this class in my Java, spring boot, hibernate application :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class Person{

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID", nullable=false)
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="PERSON_ID")
    private String personId;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NME")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Award> awards;
}
```

and let's say that this is the awards class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="award")
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class Award{

    @Id
    @Column(name="COMPOSITE_ID", nullable=false)
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="AWARD_CODE")
    private String awardCode;

    @Column(name="AWARD_NAME")
    private String awardName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID")
    private Personn person;
}
```

When I do a simple find all from my jpa repository like this :

```
List<Person> findAll();
```

I get this error :

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.my.proj.datastores.legacy.model.Person.awards, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.my.proj.datastores.legacy.model.Person.awards, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.my.proj.datastores.ngl.model.Person["awards"])]
```

Not exactly sure why... I can make the request work if I do @JsonIgnore, but I want those award children objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Eager** Loading is a design pattern in which data initialization occurs on the spot

**Lazy** Loading is a design pattern which is used to defer initialization of an object as long as it’s possible

**when lazy loading is enabled, if we pull up a Person, Award data won’t be initialized and loaded into a memory until an explicit call is made to it.**

**In eager loading strategy, if we load the Person, it will also load up all Award associated with it and will store it in a memory.**

So just use `fetch=FetchType.Eager`

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.Eager, mappedBy = "person", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Award> awards;
```

Comment: what if i have multiple eager loadings? Because in that case i get **MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags**